# How is the inside and outside of an open curve is defined?

Tags: geometry

When a person says "The *inside* of a parabola $y=x^2$" in daily conversation, it is easily assumed that his/her intention is the area $y>x^2$. I think, however, it is not always trivial for general curves such as $y=x^3$ or $y=\sin x$. How are the inside and outside defined in open curves?

This question is out of curiosity.

Comment: I would find "inside" confusing even for $y=x^2$. For graphs of the form $y=f(x)$, it's much clearer to say the region above/below the graph.

Comment: The inside of the parabola is where the focus is; all rays/lines parallel to the axis of symmetry are directed to/through the focus, and all rays originating from the focus that hit the inside of the parabola are redirected parallel to the axis of symmetry.  Lines parallel to the axis of symmetry that hit the outside of the parabola are directed away from the focus.

Comment: Generally, the terms "inside" and "outside" don't really apply to curves such as $y=\sin(x)$.  However, introducing the two-variable function $f(x,y)=y-\sin(x)$, we can identify the curve itself as the function's "zero set" —where $f(x,y)=0$— and say that it separates the plane into "positive" and "negative" regions — where $f(x,y)>0$ or $f(x,y)<0$. (Of course, one can just as easily define $g(x,y)=\sin(x)-y$, reversing the sense of "positive" and "negative".)